# Como remover valores repetidos de um dicionário?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dicionário

Por exemplo:

```
A = {2:5,4:5,7:8,9:8,11:10}
```

Deve retornar `B={11:10}` para remover os valores repetidos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso pode ser feito com um unico comando da seguinte forma:

```
from collections import Counter

B = {k: A[k] for k in A if Counter(A.values())[A[k]] == 1}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is beautiful.